# Modern treatment of bronchitis

Tags: medications, treatment, lungs, bronchitis

On the internet there are dozens or even hundreds of medicines claiming to help if you have bronchitis. But is there a modern and tested approach to treating this illness? Or has nothing really changed here during last 30-40 years?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "bronchitis"? Are you asking about acute or chronic bronchitis? Is it associated with illness, smoking, or another precipitating factor? There are many ways to treat bronchitis. More details makes for a more applicable answer.